# Why can't I attach new AWS volume to existing AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to expand the storage on an AWS EBS volume for which I'm following [this "Expanding the Storage Space of an EBS Volume on Linux" guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html).

I created a snapshot of my volume and created a new volume out of that. And I'm now trying to attach my newly created volume to my existing instance.

The instance I want to attach it to looks like this:

[image: volume list]

but when I type `Mongo` or `i-b8ed` in the instance field of the attach volume wizard I get no results:

[image: attaching volume]

[image: attaching volume 2]

I'm sure I'm in the same Availability Zone (Frankfurt) so I really don't know why it can't find the Instance.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your screenshot your instance belongs to

```
eu-central-1b
```

and your volume is in different zone

```
eu-central-1a
```

that's why it's not able to attach the volume to the instance.